# Rails - Validation Error Messages is not Appearing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having problems with validation error messages in my Rails4 application. They don't show up somehow. When they triggered, only the "Please review the problems below" message is appearing and nothing more, no error messages.

**order.rb =>**

```
Class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  ....
  attr_accessor :card_number, :card_verification
  validate :validate_card, :on => :create

  private

  def validate_card
    unless credit_card.valid?
      credit_card.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
        errors.add(:base, message)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**orders_controller.rb =>**

```
def create
  @order = Order.new(order_params)
  @order.ip_address = request.remote_ip
  @order.user_id = current_user.id

  respond_to do |format|
    if @order.save
      if @order.purchase
        format.html { render action: "success", notice: 'Perfect!' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "failure" }
      end
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
    end
  end
end
```

**/orders/new.html.rb =>**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@order, html:{class: "well"}, :method => :post) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.input :participation_id, collection: Participation.where(user_id: current_user.id), as: :select, label_method: lambda{|x| x.examination.name}, label: 'Choose' %>
  <%= f.input :first_name, label: 'Name' %>
  <%= f.input :last_name, label: 'Surname' %>
  .........
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

What is wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you are not displaying the errors. See here how the validations have been displayed on view . http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#working-with-validation-errors

Comment: where is error_notification method defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the example

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :active_customer, on: :create
 
  def active_customer
    errors.add(:customer_id, "is not active") unless customer.active?
  end
end
```

Check this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Try this>>>

```
 Class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
      ....
      attr_accessor :card_number, :card_verification
      validate :validate_card, :on => :create

      private

      def validate_card
        unless credit_card.valid?           
            errors.add(:credit_card,  "your message")           
        end
      end
 end
```

Comment: I think we need to add field on `errors.add(:field_name,"message")`  . Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. This will generate one error at a time

```
<% if @order.errors.full_messages.any? %>
  <% @order.errors.full_messages.each do |error_message| %>
    <%= error_message if @order.errors.full_messages.first == error_message %> <br />
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```